# Eigenvalues of a matrix in relation to another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{K}) $  (where $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C} \} $) invertible matrices. Prove that if $\lambda = 0 $ is an eigenvalue of matrix $C$, where $C = BA - AB ~$ then $ \lambda = 1 $ is an eigenvalue of matrix $D~$ where $D = B^{-1}A^{-1}BA$

I don't know where to start this proof, since I can't recall any eigenvalue properties that relate sum or diference of matrices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue of $C$, then there must exist an associated eigenvector. That is, there is a (non-zero) vector $v$ for which $ABv = BAv$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the determinant of $B^{-1}A^{-1}C$.

Answer (score 0):

$$B^{-1}A^{-1}BAx = B^{-1}A^{-1}ABx = 1x $$
for some $x\neq 0$ satisfying $ABx=BAx$.